# YYYY/M/D format with date with bash

Tags: bash

i have to create a string in bash which can be such this way:

```
/bla/ble/bli/2010/1/1/10/00/Afile.csv
```

where the format is YYYY/M/D/HH/mm

I was using this:

```
myDate=$(date -d@"$_initialPeriod" +'/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M')
```

but this is representing the month and the day always with two digits and that is not the requirement.

How can i use date or any another linux tool to achieve my purpose?

thank you

Comment: pipe to sed: something like `sed 's/\/0/\//g'` should work

Comment: As an aside, you _do_ want to create the day and month with two characters always, because then it sorts properly. Otherwise you get 1, 10, 11, 12, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, for the months. Which is just plain annoying. If anyone tells you otherwise, just ignore them.

Comment: There is a reason the ISO standard is the way it is :)

Comment: `date +/%Y/%-m/%-d/%H/%M` (A minute perusing `man date`.)

Comment: @Biffen Ain't nobody got time for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a hyphen, like this:

```
date -d"$_initialPeriod" +'/%Y/%-m/%-d/%H/%M'
```

Comment: i have tried to comment again but the system does not let me to do it. It should be myDate=$(date -d@"$_initialPeriod" +'/%Y/%-m/%-d/%H/%M')